# Multiple connections with tcpclient in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

can I connect to multiple `<IP, PORT>` using a single `TcpClient()` object

Can I do

```
tcpClient = new TcpClient();

tcpClient.Connect(host1,port1)
tcpClient.Connect(host2,port2)
```

or `tcpClient` object is tied to a single stream?

Comment: _"Can I do"_ -- what happened when you tried that? That should be your answer right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an XY problem to me, but regardless... If you want to connect to multiple hosts simultaneously then you will need to initialize a client per connection. Also keep in mind that synchronous listen ops on a single thread will block execution.